# Limit button click to only once

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, parse-platform

I have an activity, where upon button click (mConfirm2) it would take user to a new activity. The issue is that if a user by accident clicks multiple time on the button than I receive an unexpected error, and hence I believe the only solution would be is to allow only one click, where it wouldn't matter how many times the user click on the button, it would only count the first click.

Below is the activity

```
public class CasualEventsSingleItemActivity extends Activity {

    // Declare Variables
    String list_item_name;
    String list_item_description;
    String list_item_bac;

    String list_item_price;
    String list_item_location;

    String list_item_purchase_code;
    String single_list_item_description;




    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_events_single_item);


        ImageLoader mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(Volley.newRequestQueue(this),
                new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
            private final LruCache<String, Bitmap>
                    cache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(20);

            @Override
            public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
                return cache.get(url);
            }

            @Override
            public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
                cache.put(url, bitmap);
            }
        });


        Intent i = getIntent();
        list_item_name = i.getStringExtra("list_item_name");
        list_item_location = i.getStringExtra("list_item_location");
        list_item_bac = i.getStringExtra("list_item_bac");
        list_item_price = i.getStringExtra("list_item_price");
        list_item_purchase_code = i.getStringExtra("list_item_purchase_code");


        single_list_item_description = i.getStringExtra("single_list_item_description");

        TextView txtname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView txtlocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.location);
        TextView txtsdescription = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sdescription);


        NetworkImageView hsvimage1 = (NetworkImageView) findViewById(R.id.hsvimage1);
        NetworkImageView hsvimage2 = (NetworkImageView) findViewById(R.id.hsvimage2);
        NetworkImageView hsvimage3 = (NetworkImageView) findViewById(R.id.hsvimage3);

        // Get image URLs from your previous network request...
        // I could not determine where this is stored from code in your question.
        String url1 = list_item_bac;   // e.g. http://example.com/images/image1.png
        String url2 = list_item_bac;
        String url3 = list_item_bac;

        // Set the URL of the image that should be loaded into this view, and
        // specify the ImageLoader that will be used to make the request.
        hsvimage1.setImageUrl(url1, mImageLoader);
        hsvimage2.setImageUrl(url2, mImageLoader);
        hsvimage3.setImageUrl(url3, mImageLoader);

        // Set results to the TextViews
        txtname.setText(list_item_name);
        txtlocation.setText(list_item_location);
        txtsdescription.setText(single_list_item_description);


        Button mConfirm2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bConfirm2);
        mConfirm2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();

               // Create the class and the columns
                currentUser.saveInBackground();


                currentUser.put("ActivityName", list_item_name); 

                currentUser.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);

                        if (e == null) {
                            // Success!
                            Intent intent = new Intent(CasualEventsSingleItemActivity.this, usermatch.class);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                        else {
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CasualEventsSingleItemActivity.this);
                            builder.setMessage(e.getMessage())
                                .setTitle(R.string.signup_error_title)
                                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                            dialog.show();
                        }
                   }
               });
                //CasualEventsSingleItemActivity.this.startActivity(new Intent(CasualEventsSingleItemActivity.this, MatchingActivity.class));
            }
        });


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add **setEnabled(false)** into your onclick method

```
        Button mConfirm2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bConfirm2);
        mConfirm2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mConfirm2.setEnabled(false);
                ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();

               // Create the class and the columns
                currentUser.saveInBackground();


                currentUser.put("ActivityName", list_item_name); 

                currentUser.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);

                        if (e == null) {
                            // Success!
                            Intent intent = new Intent(CasualEventsSingleItemActivity.this, usermatch.class);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                        else {
                            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CasualEventsSingleItemActivity.this);
                            builder.setMessage(e.getMessage())
                                .setTitle(R.string.signup_error_title)
                                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                            dialog.show();
                        }
                   }
               });
                //CasualEventsSingleItemActivity.this.startActivity(new Intent(CasualEventsSingleItemActivity.this, MatchingActivity.class));
            }
        });
```